# How to strip a forward slash from a string

Tags: python

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  

>>> s = "www.example.com/help"
>>> s.strip('/')
>>> 'www.example.com/help'    #expected 'www.example.comhelp'
>>> t = "/blah/blah/"
>>> t.strip('/')
>>> 'blah/blah'    #expected 'blahblah'
>>> s.strip('w.')
>>> 'example.com/help'    #expected 'examplecom/help'
>>> f = 'www.example.com'
>>> f.strip('.')
>>> 'www.example.com'    #expected 'wwwexamplecom'
>>> f.strip('comw.')
>>> 'example'    #as expected
```

Can someone please explain why str.strip doesn't seem to work as promised?

From the documentation:

> str.strip([chars])
>
> > Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

Comment: The documentation says: with the *leading* and *trailing* characters removed. And the function does exactly this. It removes only the *leading* and *trailing* characters.

Comment: It says right in the documentation you cited, strip _leading_ and _trailing_ characters, not characters in the middle.

Comment: Right! Now that was really a dumb question *|covering my face|*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> str.strip([chars])
>
> > Return a copy of the string with the **leading and trailing** characters removed.

Use this to replace a string anywhere:

```
s.replace('/', '')
```

Answer (score 8):

strip will only remove **leading and trailing characters**.

I would suggest using:

```
s.replace('/', '')
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

**One more way to do so**

```
    In [19]: s = 'abc.com/abs'
    In [29]: exclude = '/'
    In [31]: s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)
    In [32]: s
    Out[32]: 'abc.comabs'
```